# Xcode 4 storyboard, textfields not wanting to connect to IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode

So in the storyboard i have a UIViewController class called FormViewController. I set the ViewController in the storyboard to use that:

[image: custom class]

I then have the three text fields in the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FormViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *firstName;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *lastName;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *email;

- (IBAction) save:(id)sender;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;

@end
```

However, when i try to connect the ones in the storyboard to the view controller, it doesnt pop up.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextField` and `UITextView` are two very different classes—you have created `UITextField` instances but your outlets are typed as `UITextView`.

Just change your outlet types to `UITextField` and all should be well!

(`UITextView`, for the record, is a scrolling, often editable field, more like a word processor.)

Comment: Figured it was something terribly obvious such as that. Thanks :)